# Unable to compile my project with libxml2 and XCode 4.4

Tags: ios, xcode, osx-mountain-lion, libxml2

My project was working without errors on `XCode 4.2` on `Lion`. Now I'm running `Mountain Lion` with `XCode 4.4` and when I try to build the project it gives me an error that `tree.h` file cannot be found. I checked the header search path and it was correct. I searched the web for such an error and found the same solution on many different pages but couldn't understand that particular solution, see for example [this page](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.os.apple.macports.user/26895).

How can I solve this problem? Alternately, can you clarify the weird solution that is spread all over the internet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to add another header search path which is: `$(SDKROOT)/usr/include/libxml2`. This fixed the problem.

Comment: You should mark this as correct or state that this fixed the problem so people know this fixed the problem without comparing your asker and answer names

Comment: If you have a space in your path (usually in the name of your 'Xcode.app' as I called mine 'Xcode 4.5.app') you have to put this path in quotes. Also, SDK_DIR is better than SDKROOT as you'll be shown the full path. So use: "${SDK_DIR}/usr/include/libxml2" and mark as recursive.

Comment: Thank you so much, Wex, I have tried a lot of things, none of them worked, and then I found out that I also head renamed my Xcode.app with spaces.

Answer (score 2):

Go in the XCode preferences and install the command line tools.

Comment: When all the other tips didn't completely fix it, this did the trick.